# SSH Permission denied (publickey) fails on Ubuntu but succeeds on MacOS

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have two machines, a MacOS and an Ubuntu. I have been working sucessfully on the MacOS, i.e. I can use my public key to connect via SSH to a server. However, when trying to use the same private & public key on a new Ubuntu machine in order to connect to the server it fails.

One to thing to note, is with MacOS it is suing SSH v1 and Ubuntu SSH v2.

**1. MacOS**

```
/home/richardm/.ssh/id_rsa
/home/richardm/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
/home/richardm/.ssh/config
/home/richardm/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Config

```
Host *
AddKeysToAgent yes
UseKeychain yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
ServerAliveInterval 240
User = richard
ForwardAgent yes
StrictHostKeyChecking=no
IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Terminal output:

$ ssh -A -J richard@XX.XXX.XXX.XXX dev-myco-node01 -vvv

```
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/richardm/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:CKEVmfXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXFrkI explicit agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: /Users/richardm/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:CKEVmfXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXFrkI explicit agent
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:CKEVmfXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXFrkI
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512 SHA256:CKEVmfXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXFrkI
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
```

**2. Ubuntu**

```
/home/richardm/.ssh/id_rsa
/home/richardm/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
/home/richardm/.ssh/config
/home/richardm/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Config

```
Host *
AddKeysToAgent yes
#  UseKeychain yes
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
ServerAliveInterval 240
User = richard
ForwardAgent yes
StrictHostKeyChecking=no
IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Terminal output:

$ ssh -A -J richard@XX.XXX.XXX.XXX richard@dev-myco-node01 -vvv

```
debug3: preferred publickey
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: 
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/richardm/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:CKEVmfXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXFrkI explicit agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/richardm/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:CKEVmfXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXFrkI explicit agent
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: using publickey with RSA SHA256:CKEVmfXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXFrkI
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512 SHA256:CKEVmfXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXFrkI
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for RSA "/home/richardm/.ssh/id_rsa" from agent: agent refused operation
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
richard@XX.XXX.XXX.XXX: Permission denied (publickey).
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote
```

Comment: In general - do not only debug server issues client-side, also (first) look at the server log files for error reports. -|- In addition when using the `-J`. ProxyJump ensure that you can log in to the jumphost before debugging the second stage. -|- If you're talking about SSH 1 & 2 with regards to  protocol versions, SSH v1 is deprecated. https://undeadly.org/cgi?action=article;sid=20170501005206

Comment: @HBruijn, thank you for the info. I now try: ssh -A richard@XX.XXX.XXX.XXX -vvv to try connect just to the proxy, but this fails too. debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512 SHA256:CKEVXXXXXXXXFrkI
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for RSA "/home/richardm/.ssh/id_rsa" from agent: agent refused operation

Answer (score 1):

RSA SHA-1 hash keys are depricated on new ubuntu version. For quick solution you can enable the RSA keys on the local computer, add these line in ~/.ssh/config or /etc/ssh/sshd_config and restart the sshd service.

```
Host *
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa
```

However, you are recommend to generate the new secure type keys like ed25519 or rsa-sha2-512 Hash.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but unfortunately that didn't fix it, but the error message is different.

Comment: debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/richardm.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:XXXX explicit agent
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/richardm/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:XXXXX explicit agent
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: using publickey with RSA SHA256:XXXX
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512 SHA256:XXXX
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for RSA "/home/richardm/.ssh/id_rsa" from agent: agent refused operation richard@XX.XXX.XXX.XXX: Permission denied (publickey)

Comment: Clearly indicated from your quesiton you are facing issue with the RSA Hash. Have you tried manually adding the keys ?
ssh-agent /bin/bash, ssh-add /home/richardm/.ssh/id_rsa

Comment: I copied the ~/.ssh from the Mac to the Ubuntu laptop, hoping that it would use the same keys and provide the same access. I did set the permissions to: chmod 700 ~/.ssh, chmod 644 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub, chmod 700 ~/.ssh/id_rsa (I have also tried setting all to 777).

Comment: Setting up 777 will fail. The permission required for keys is 600. There should be no issues with copying keys from MacOS to Ubuntu.